# How to find the probability that the number of boxes which must be selected to obtain all three blue boxes is greater than or equal to $5$.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve this problem.

> There are four identical red boxes and three identical blue boxes. If the boxes are randomly selected one at a time without replacement, find the probability that number of boxes which must be selected in order to obtain all three blue boxes is at least five.

I tried

1. We select 3 boxes and all boxes are blue. In this case, we have one way.
2. We select 4 boxes and there are three blue boxes, then we have three cases: RED BLUE BLUE BLUE, BLUE BLUE RED BLUE, BLUE RED BLUE BLUE.
3. We select 5 boxes and there are three blue boxes. The end box must blue. The number of select is `C(4, 2) = 6`.
4. We select 6 boxes and there are three blue boxes. The end box must blue. The number of select is `C(5, 3) = 10`.
5. We select 7 boxes and there are three blue boxes. The end box must blue. The number of select is `C(6, 4) = 15`.

The probability to select 3 boxes such that the number of boxes is greater than or equal to 5 is
$$(6 + 10 + 15)/(1 + 3  + 6 + 10 + 15)=31/35.$$
Is this correct?
If the blue boxes and red boxed are different. How to find The probability to select 3 boxes such that the number of boxes is greater than or equal to 5?

Comment: Clarification requested: "Find the probability to select 3 boxes such that the number of boxes is greater than or equal to 5".  Please re-state the question as if I was $18$ years old, and you are trying to make it impossible for me to be in any way confused about what the math problem is.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have just edited.

Comment: Still unclear.  Please tell me if this is what you intend.  You are given that some of the $7$ boxes were selected, at random.  You are also given that the number of boxes selected was greater than or equal to $5$.  What is the probability that all $3$ blue boxes were selected?  **Is this what you are asking**?

Comment: Yes. I want to some of the 7 boxes were selected, at random. I am also given that the number of boxes selected was greater than or equal to 5, and probability that all 3 blue boxes were selected.

Comment: As I understand the problem, boxes are randomly selected one at a time without replacement.  We want to find the probability that the number of boxes which must be selected in order to obtain all three blue boxes is at least five.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig There is a language difficulty with the OP (i.e.original poster), so your interpretation may be correct.  My answer reflects a different interpretation, namely that you are given that at least $5$ boxes were selected, and based on this premise wish to calculate the probability that all $3$ blue boxes were selected.

Comment: I assumed that the comment of N.F.Taussig is correct, changed my answer accordingly, and then got the same answer that you did, namely $\displaystyle \frac{31}{35}$.  However, for what it's worth, I assumed that there were exactly $4$ boxes selected and that it was then desired to compute the probability that the number of blue boxes selected (out of the $4$ total boxes selected) was less than $3$ blue boxes.

Comment: By the way: +1 to your question.  I am finally able to reverse-engineer your logic.  Although you took a totally different (and creative) approach, I think that your logic was perfectly valid and your math was accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**New Interpretation**

There is disagreement about what the OP is asking.  It has been suggested that my original interpretation is wrong.  In hindsight, it does seem very plausible that I was mistaken.  Therefore, I left my original interpretation at the very end of my answer, *just in case* it turns out to be what the OP intended.

The new interpretation is to compute the probability that in the first $4$ boxes selected (without replacement), less than $3$ blue boxes were selected.  This would correspond to there needing to be at least $5$ boxes selected, before all of the blue boxes were selected.

The number of ways that $4$ boxes can be selected out of $7$ is $\displaystyle \binom{7}{4} = 35$.

The number of ways that $m$ blue boxes were among the $4$ selected boxes [with $m \in \{0,1,2,3\}$] is

$$\binom{3}{m} \times \binom{4}{4 - m}.$$

This is based on the idea that if there were $m$ blue boxes (out of $3$ total blue boxes) selected, then there were $(4 - m)$ red boxes (out of $4$ total red boxes) selected.

Therefore, the desired computation is

$$\frac{1}{\binom{7}{4}} \times $$

$$\left[\binom{3}{0} \times \binom{4}{4}\right] ~+~ 
\left[\binom{3}{1} \times \binom{4}{3}\right] ~+~ 
\left[\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{4}{2}\right].$$

This equals
$$\frac{1}{35} \times [1 + 12 + 18] = \frac{31}{35}.$$

**Edit**
A shortcut, based on my approach would be to compute $~1 - ~$ the probability that in $4$ selected boxes, exactly $3$ of them were blue.

This would be

$$1 - \frac{\binom{3}{3} \times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{7}{4}} ~=~ 1 - \frac{4}{35} = \frac{31}{35}.$$

---

---

---

---

---

**Old Interpretation**

I am interpreting the OP (i.e. original poster's) intent to be that you are given that at least $5$ boxes were selected (without replacement), and wish to calculate the probability that all of the $3$ blue boxes were selected.

---

Let $k$ denote the number of boxes that were selected, where $k \in \{5,6,7\}$.

Based on this, let $p(k)$ denote the (relative) probability that $k$ boxes were selected.

Assuming that $k$ boxes were selected, let $f(k)$ denote the probability that all $3$ blue boxes were selected.

Then, the desired computation is

$$\sum_{k=5}^7 \left[p(k) \times f(k)\right].\tag1 $$

There are clearly $2^7$ equally likely possibilities of the (raw) selection of boxes, because (presumably) each box either was selected [probability $= (1/2)$] or was not selected [probability $= (1/2)$].

Therefore, the relative probabilites are $[\binom{7}{7} = 1]$ versus $[\binom{7}{6} = 7]$ versus $[\binom{7}{5} = 21]$ with respect to the relative probabilities of either $7, 6$, or $5$ boxes being selected.

Therefore,

$$p(7), p(6), p(5) ~=~  
\frac{\binom{7}{7}}{29}, \frac{\binom{7}{6}}{29}, \frac{\binom{7}{5}}{29} ~~\text{respectively}.\tag2 $$

If $k$ boxes were selected [with $k \in \{5,6,7\}$], then the chance that all $3$ blue boxes were selected is

$$f(k) = \frac{\binom{4}{k-3}}{\binom{7}{k}}. \tag3 $$

The explanation for this is that in (3) above, the denominator represents the number of ways that the $k$ boxes could be selected.  Further, if all $3$ blue boxes were selected, then $k-3$ red boxes were selected from the 4 red boxes.  Therefore, the numerator reflects the number of ways of choosing $k-3$ red boxes from the $4$ red boxes.

---

Utilizing the expressions in (1), (2), and (3) above, the desired computation is

$$\sum_{k=5}^7 \left[p(k) \times f(k)\right]$$

$$ ~=~
\left[\frac{\binom{7}{7}}{29} \times 
\frac{\binom{4}{4}}{\binom{7}{7}}\right] ~+~ 
\left[\frac{\binom{7}{6}}{29} \times 
\frac{\binom{4}{3}}{\binom{7}{6}}\right] ~+~
\left[\frac{\binom{7}{5}}{29} \times 
\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{7}{5}}\right].\tag4 $$

Simplifying the math in (4) above gives

$$\frac{1}{29} \times [1 + 4 + 6] = \frac{11}{29}.$$

Comment: Based on the proposed solution in the question itself, I'm pretty sure that interpretation proposed by N.F. Taussig is correct.

Answer (score 3):

Your work is correct but it can be simplified. We need to find the probability that $5$ draws or more are needed to select all the $3$ blue boxes. In other words in the first $4$ draws, we have less than $3$ blue boxes. So the desired probability is,

$ \displaystyle P = \left[{7 \choose 4} - {3 \choose 3}{4 \choose 1}\right] / {7 \choose 4} = \frac{31}{35}$

Explanation: There are ${7 \choose 4}$ ways to choose first $4$ boxes. To count favorable cases, we then remove all cases from it where $3$ blue boxes were selected in the first $4$ draws or less.

Comment: Under the assumption that there were $4$ boxes selected, rather than $3$ boxes (re the new interpretation at the start of my answer) then wouldn't the probability of selecting $3$ blue boxes out of $4$ total boxes be $$\frac{\binom{3}{3} \times \binom{4}{1}}{\binom{7}{4}}?$$

Comment: @user2661923 thanks. I had misinterpreted the question.

Comment: You and me both.  Actually, while your simplification (which I also included) is certainly right, it would have required that the OP conjure a totally different vision of the problem.